# How can I continue a loop inside exception handling?

Tags: python, loops, exception, grid

I am creating a simple program that operates using Moore's Neighborhood. So given a grid, row, and a column it should return the amount of cells in the vicinity of the position that contain a 1. It works, except when given a position on the edge of the grid. Since it is checking all grids surrounding it, it throws an IndexError when it tries to check a position outside of the grid. What I want it to do is just ignore it without stopping, throwing an error, or manipulating my results, and move onto the next one. But I'm not sure how, I tried doing an exception on the IndexError but it quits out of the loop once it encounters one.

```
def count_neighbours(grid, row, col):
    count = 0
    pos = grid[row][col]
    try:
        for cell in [grid[row+1][col],    #(0,-1) All relative to pos
                     grid[row-1][col],    #(0,1)
                     grid[row+1][col+1],  #(1,-1)
                     grid[row+1][col-1],  #(-1,-1)
                     grid[row][col-1],    #(-1,0)
                     grid[row][col+1],    #(1,0)
                     grid[row-1][col+1],  #(1,-1)
                     grid[row-1][col-1]]: #(-1,1)
            if cell == 1:
                count += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return count

assert count_neighbours(((1, 1, 1),
                         (1, 1, 1),
                         (1, 1, 1),), 0, 2) == 3
```

Comment: What if I were to do a check for the indexes of each cell and if it doesn't throw an exception I add it to a list of valid cells? Then loop through that list and check for the value?

Comment: Regardless of what else is wrong with your code, note that `IndexError`s _won't_ be generated for calculated negative `row ± 1` and `col ± 1` values because Python allows indices less than zero (they wrap around, i.e. they're interpreted as meaning `len(object)+index`).

Comment: P.S. A relatively simple solution the negative indices issue would be to add an empty row and column to your `grid` and use 1-based indexing for the `row` and `col` position parameters passed to the function. That way the smallest offset values calculated would be zero for all valid `row, col` position values since these will always refer to empty cells and therefore not be counted.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is stopping because you are wrapping the entire loop in a try except you want something like this

```
def count_neighbours(grid, row, col):                                                   count = 0                                                               
    pos = grid[row][col]                                                    
    for cell in [[row+1,col],    #(0,-1) All relative to pos           
                 [row-1,col],    #(0,1)                                
                 [row+1,col+1],  #(1,-1)                                
                 [row+1,col-1],  #(-1,-1)                               
                 [row,col-1],    #(-1,0)                                
                 [row,col+1],    #(1,0)                                 
                 [row-1,col+1],  #(1,-1)                                
                 [row-1,col-1]]: #(-1,1)                                
        try:                                                            
            temp_cell = grid[cell[0]][cell[1]]                                
            if temp_cell == 1:                                                   
                count += 1                                                  
        except IndexError:                                                      
            pass                                                                
    return count                                                            

assert count_neighbours(((1, 1, 1),                                         
                         (1, 1, 1),                                         
                         (1, 1, 1),), 0, 2) == 3
```

Comment: It is still throwing the same error, I think from the list in the for loop. And I'm drawing a blank, may I ask what cell = grid[cell[0],cell[1]] is exactly doing?

Comment: it should be grid[cell[0]][cell[1]] I had a typo but it is grabbing the the first and second element of each list its the equivalent of what your cell in the for loop was prolly shouldve named it something else

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach, first compute the valid coords for a given point and then check for ones.

For instance you could use this function:

```
def compute_coords_around(x, y, boundary):
    xcoords = [x-1, x, x+1]
    ycoords = [y-1, y, y+1]
    valid_coords = []

    for xc in xcoords:
        for yc in ycoords:
            if xc <= boundary and yc <= boundary:
                valid_coords.append((xc,yc))

    return valid_coords
```

and lets say you want check for adjacent cells of (2, 2) in a matrix of 3x3. You know the maximum value of a column or a row is 2. So you can:

```
compute_coords_around(2, 2, 2)
```

That will give you the list:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

while:

```
compute_coords_around(1, 1, 2)
```

give you:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Then your code could be modified to:

```
def count_neighbours(grid, row, col):
    count = 0
    pos = grid[row][col]
    for (x, y) in compute_coords_around(row, col, len(grid) - 1)
        if grid[x][y] == 1:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You need finer-grained exception handling (and your algorithm needs to explicitly check for otherwise legal -- in Python -- indices less than zero). Here's one way to achieve both:

```
OFFSETS = ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
           ( 0, -1),          ( 0, 1),
           ( 1, -1), ( 1, 0), ( 1, 1))

def count_neighbours(grid, row, col):
    count = 0
    for dr, dc in OFFSETS:
        try:
            x, y = row+dr, col+dc
            if x < 0 or y < 0:  # Disallow negative indices.
                raise IndexError
            if grid[x][y] == 1:  # Could also cause an IndexError.
                count += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return count

assert count_neighbours(((1, 1, 1),
                         (1, 1, 1),
                         (1, 1, 1),), 0, 2) == 3
```

However having to add an explicit check for negative indices in the inner-most loop is kind of ugly. As I mentioned in a comment, adding an extra row and column to the grid would certainly simplify the processing, as illustrated below:

```
OFFSETS = ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
           ( 0, -1),          ( 0, 1),
           ( 1, -1), ( 1, 0), ( 1, 1))

def count_neighbours(grid, row, col):
    count = 0
    for dr, dc in OFFSETS:
        try:
            if grid[row+dr][col+dc] == 1:
                count += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return count

# Note the changed position coordinate arguments.
assert count_neighbours(((0, 0, 0, 0),
                         (0, 1, 1, 1),
                         (0, 1, 1, 1),
                         (0, 1, 1, 1),), 1, 3) == 3
```